# Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting - TIME

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to make a spread sheet with conditional formatting. I don't know how to go about this.
What i'm trying to do is Check in Times. So Bob Will depart our shop at 8:00AM and he will check in with dispatch when he gets half way to his arrival location. Then he will check in again when he arrives on site..

I need the Check in half way and the Check in upon arrival to change colours. If Bob checked in 15 Min early either half way or upon arrival i need that cell to go YELLOW.. If bob checks in on time i need that cell to go ORANGE and if Bob checks in 15 min late i need that cell to go RED,

However the departure time and arrival time will be different on every line because not everyone leaves at the same time and not everyone is going to the same location..

Pretty much i need a time format so that when i say departure is at (what ever time) 8:00 and check in time should be 10:00 but Bob got there at 10:30 i need that cell to go red because he is late..

Comment: Sounds great, please show us your research.  What have you tried already?  Where are you getting stuck? What's your specific question to us?

Comment: There's a few ways this can be handled, depending on your spreadsheet layout and how much you're willing to adjust it. A simple way would involve helper columns that define the "early check-in" and "late check-in" extremes, and then use a formula in the Conditional Formatting definition to compare against those times. A slightly more complex means would be to do without the helper columns, and just incorporate the formulas that would have been used in those columns into the formula used for Conditional Formatting.

Answer (score 4):

(This is my first answer posting on this site so advice of how to improve my response is welcomed)

I don't know how your sheet is set up but the easiest way to get this to work is to setup columns like this:
A: Employee
B: Departure Time
C: Expected Half-Way Time
D: Actual Half-Way Time
E: Expected Arrival Time
F: Actual Arrival Time

How you populate those fields are up to you
However, once they're in, you can use conditional formatting on columns D and F using formulas like this: (multiplying by 1440 turns a date/time number into minutes)

> =((C2-D2)*1440)>15   (Yellow, Stop if True)
>
> =((D2-C2)*1440)>15   (Red, Stop if True)
>
> =D2>0                (Orange)

This setup turns the Actual Half-Way Time Yellow if it's 15 minutes before the expected time, Red if it's 15 minutes after, and Orange if it's any other non-zero value (ie, when the time is put it and not 15 min early or late since that would have been caught by thte previous formulas)

Note that you'll have to put in 3 different conditional format conditions and you need to make sure the Orange one is at the bottom so it only gets checked after Red and Yellow are checked first.

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing the [original version](https://superuser.com/revisions/786557/1) of my answer, I realized that consolidation of all necessary formatting formulas was actually a bit easier than I'd expected. That, and I was using the wrong colors. Here's how you can do everything you need, fully within Conditional Formatting.

All fields below are manual-entered. Make sure that columns C, E, and F are formatted in a Date/Time format.

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the Conditional Formatting rules. No need to use "Stop If True" here, since the formulas for "early" and "late" don't overlap. Priority ordering of "early" and "late" rules doesn't matter, but you do need to make sure that "on time" is the last one processed.

[image]

Formulas:

Early Halfway (Apply to column E):

```
=E1<=C1+TIME(0,D1/2-15,0)
```

Late Halfway (Apply to column E):

```
=E1>=C1+TIME(0,D1/2+15,0)
```

Early Arrival (Apply to column F):

```
=F1<=C1+TIME(0,D1-15,0)
```

Late Arrival (Apply to column F):

```
=F1>=C1+TIME(0,D1+15,0)
```

On Time (Apply to E:F; Make sure it's the last rule processed.):

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("Actual",E1)),NOT(ISBLANK(E1)))
```

Effectively, the "Early Halfway" rule translates to:

> Take the Travel Time, divide it by two, subtract fifteen minutes, and add it to the Departure Time. If the Actual Halfway Time is less than or equal to that value, highlight the cell.

You can probably figure out the rest of the Early/Late rules from there. Note: The Early rules will trigger a false-positive on an empty cell if Departure Time is filled in on the same line. Given the "On Time" rule I've used, (see below) you can probably figure out how to prevent this if you want.

The "On Time" rule is pretty much a default catch-all that's meant to trigger on anything except the headers or an empty cell. This keeps your spreadsheet looking neat, while at the same time being a relatively simple (read: no greater-than/less-than or maths) "anything that didn't match the others" type of rule. Effectively, it translates to:

> If a search for the string "Actual" results in an error (i.e.: "Actual" does not exist in the cell), *AND* the cell is *NOT* blank, highlight the cell.

Of course, as already stated, the "On Time" rule only works properly if it's the last rule processed.