# How to use conditional formatting to highlight specific days of the week AND time periods?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting, date-time

This answer regarding formatting on date time information ***[Excel 2010 Conditional Formatting - TIME](https://superuser.com/questions/786428/excel-2010-conditional-formatting-time)*** is a very, very technical answer that, in truth, I don't really understand! Hey-ho, I can deal with my ignorance....

However, this answer is also very exciting as it begins to prove there is a formulaic answer to my excel conditional formatting question;

How would i highlight a column of cells, holding date and time format (e.g.; Mon 22/10/2014 17:34) to pick out the times that are a) Monday to Friday, and b) between a given time period (e.g.; 15:00-15:45)?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. What have you attempted so far? Are the cells actually formatted as date/time or is it text?

Answer (score 0):

Look up `Time & Date functions` in the Excel help.

Example: `WEEKDAY()` will take a date and give back a numeric value, representing the number of days from monday (or sunday=1... sat=7, if you set the second argument to 1 instead of 0).

Additionally `TEXT()` will allow to pick out portions of a "date & time" (using the same syntax as custom formatting),
so the Formula to use for conditional formatting may be put this way (based on cell A1):

`=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(A1;0)<5;TEXT(A1;"HH:MM")>"14:00";TEXT(A1;"HH:MM")<"15:00");True;False)`

HTH to get you further